# Error while hosting angular 13 application in IIS

Tags: python, flask, iis

[image]

I created a angular 13 application using
ng new Application name
served the application using ng serve
it works fine. I built the same application and tried hosting it in IIS by creating a new website. But it is not executing in server. I have proper web.config file too. What could be the issue

Comment: You are using the legacy way to host a Python/Flask app on IIS via FastCGI, so anything can happen. Microsoft recommends HttpPlatformHandler, https://halfblood.pro/running-flask-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/

Comment: Sorry i had given a wrong title. I am trying to host angular application

Comment: @deaponn any idea ?

Comment: If your mere goal is to host an Angular web app (not any Python/Flask), ask your server administrators to remove that Python FastCGI handler from this IIS application for you and stop such errors from occurring.

Comment: Just seeing your comment! Thanks @Lex Li

Answer (score 0):

I had selected * (in file type) and mapped to a python.exe in handler mapping in IIS (whose name was flaskhandler) for this site. As a result any application hosted in this site was being executed by python. On removing the mapping issue was resolved.

Comment: If you can mark your answer, it will lead more people in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Download and Install Httpplatformhandler on IIS using Windows Platform
Installer. Or download from this [link](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler).

You can refer to the following steps to host a Flask web application using **Httpplatformhandler**.

> **For Flask physical path is a path to app.py of your application. Add web.config where your flask is defined.**
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <configuration>
>     <system.webServer>
>         <handlers>
>             <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" > modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
>         </handlers>
>         <httpPlatform startupTimeLimit="10" startupRetryCount="10" stdoutLogEnabled="true" processPath="C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" arguments="app.py">
>             <environmentVariables>
>                 <environmentVariable name="foo" value="bar"/>
>             </environmentVariables>
>         </httpPlatform>
>     </system.webServer>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> In the above web.config, httpPlaform is handling the Python process. ProcessPath is a physical path to python executable. Just like you provide python path in a
> windows environment variable. To access the python executable. Here
> you have to provide python.exe in processPath.
>
> Arguments are the same argument you pass running any python web
> application. For eg. python app.py -p 5005 where app.py to port number
> all are arguments. In the above application, app.py is passed to run
> flask application.
>
> **Add Permission to Flask Application and Python folder where your executable is present.**
>
> 1. Open folder properties.
> 2. In Security click on Edit then click on Add
> 3. Enter object name as IIS AppPool\<yourappname>
> 4. Click on the check name if its present click ok and allow permissions you wanted to give then apply it.
>
> **Run your application**

For more information, please refer to this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@akshay.mewada7/host-flask-and-django-web-application-with-windows-iis-httpplatformhanlder-83e831ce91bc).

Comment: I am hosting an angular application. Let me update the title.

Comment: However, that tutorial missed several key details and does not guarantee successful configuration.